# Can you help me figuring out how the triangle inequality is being used here?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> [image]

How is the triangle inequality being used in the first and second inequalities? In the first one, for example, looking at $d(x_n,y_n)$, I know I'd have:

$$d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,z) + d(z,y_n)$$

for some $z$. But if I choose $z=x$ of $z=y$, it won't get similar. I suspect the inequality is being used twice but I can't see how.

Comment: You have a sum of norms of chained vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prove the first inequality you mention. The second is similar.

Note that by the triangle inequality

$$d(x_n,y_n)\leq d(x_n,x) + d(x,y_n) \quad (1)$$

and by another application of the triangle inequality

$$d(x,y_n) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,y_n) \quad (2)$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we see

$$d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,x) + (d(x,y)+d(y,y_n))$$

so yeah you are right, it is just the triangle inequality applied twice.